# Could not resolve io.github.lizhangqu:coreprogress:1.0.2 in React Native during react-native-compressor installing

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, react-native-cli

I am using react-native-0.70.6 and during the installation of react-native-compressor-1.6.1
I am getting an error when running `npx react-native-run-android` the error is
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-compressor:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-compressor:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.github.lizhangqu:coreprogress:1.0.2.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-compressor
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Skipped due to earlier error

Please help to fix the error...